Why ChromeDevTools cannot destructure property of props but Firefox can?
I'm currently making a Messaging App with Socket.io to have live chat. My app architecture is based like this :
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <SocketProvider>
        <ChatProvider>
          <Layout>
            <Outlet />
          </Layout>
        </ChatProvider>
      </SocketProvider>
    </>
  );
} 

Inside this Outlet, when user is logged in, the main Component will be Home who will always display Navbar on the left and then actualPage state from the ChatContext on the left to display settings, chat, and others stuffs...
On my Navbar I have GroupsList who fetch group data related to user and who give it with .map for each Group.
Group is a btn who change actualPage state to display chat.
Here is code to try to reproduce :
GroupsList =

import Group from './Group';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


export default function GroupsList() {


  const [groups, setGroups] = useState('');


  useEffect(() => {
    const getGroups = async () => {
    const data = {success: true, groupMemberships: [{id: 0, name: "Group1"}, {id: 1, name: "Group 2"]}

    setGroups(data);
    };

    getGroups();
  }, []);


  return (
    <ul>
      <span>
        Groups
      </span>
      {groups.groupMemberships.map((group) => (
        <li
          key={group.group.id}
          
        >
          <Group
            name={group.group.name}
            groupId={group.group.id}
            
          />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

Group =
import GroupChat from './GroupChat';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function Group({ name, groupId }) {
 

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setActualPage(<GroupChat groupId={groupId} />)
 
        }}
      >
        <div>
          <span>{name}</span>
        </div>
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

Group.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  groupId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};


GroupChat =




import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


export default function GroupChat({ groupId = 1 }) {
  console.log(groupId);
  const data = {success: true, messages: [] }
  
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setMessages(data.messages);
      
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <>
<div>//Content with send input</div>
     </>
  );
}

GroupChat.propTypes = {
  groupId: PropTypes.string,
};

Then GroupChat use groupId prop for POST data when clicked on Send button.
Everything is working on Firefox but not on Chrome, it happens when I click on the Group button to display the chat, and give me " TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'groupId' of 'undefined' as it is undefined. "
I've tried it on Firefox and everything is working.
I've added several console.log inside each component and groupId is always OK, and even in GroupChat it's crashing on line export default function GroupChat({ groupId }) { but the console.log just behind is correctly displaying the value.
